# Question about Cauchy Criterion for Riemann Integrability

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading the book "Theories of Integration" by Douglas Kurtz, and I have a question about the following proof from the book.

[image]

[image]

Specifically, would it be valid to replace the argument that follows "It remains to show that A satisfies the Definition [of Riemann Integral]" by:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $\{S(f,P,\{t_i\}_{i=1}^n)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$ ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I know that the original sequence converges to A, so the sequence that I constructed by replacing only the Kth term (while not changing the other terms) of the original sequence also converges to the same limit A. I basically let {S(f,P,t_i)} play the role of Kth term in the original Cauchy sequence, without affecting the behavior of the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your assumption, we have (simplifying the notations) $$|S(f,P)-S(f,P_k)|<\frac 1K<\varepsilon \qquad \forall\; k \ge K$$ and so $$|S(f,P)-A|\le\frac 1K<\varepsilon$$ taking the limit for $k \rightarrow \infty\;$.

If you mean this, you are right.